# Radicable Groups

Tags: group-theory

A group $G$ is said to be radicable if each element is an $n$th power for every positive integer $n$, ie, $G$ is radicable if the equation $x^n = a$ has a solution in $G$ for every positive integer $n$ and every $a \in G$.

I'm reading the paper "A finiteness condition for verbal conjugacy classes in a group" by J.M Muñoz-Escolano and P. Shumyatsky and in this paper, in the Lemma 2.6 they consider a group $A$ radicable and Chernikov and claim that such a group has no subgroup of finite index.

My question is: Radicable Groups has no subgroup of finite index? Why? Or the hypothesis that the group is required to be Chernikov for this to be valid? In any case as proof this statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume $A$ has a subgroup $U$ of finite index $n$. Then for each element $g$ of $A$ we have $g^{n!} \in U$ (in fact $g^{n!}$ is in the kernel of the natural action of $A$ on $A/U$ which is contained in $U$). Take now any element $h$ of $A$ which does not belong to $U$ and consider an element $g$ with $g^{n!}=h$ which exists since $A$ is radicable. Then $g^{n!}$ does not belong to $U$ which is a contradiction.
(Please note that $n!$ is not the smallest one can do here but that does not really matter).

Answer (score 2):

Just remember that quotients of radicable groups are radicable too and a finite group cannot be radicable. Thus, if $N \leq G$ is such that $[G:N]<\infty$ then $G/N$ is finite, yielding a condradiction.

Comment: @SebastianSchoennebe thanks